# Conditional AllowAnonymous

Tags: asp.net, security, asp.net-core-mvc

the default template of asp.net mvc6 with individual account has the following methods in the `AccountController`

```
// GET: /Account/Register
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult Register()
{
    return View();
}

//
// POST: /Account/Register
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model) {
    ...
}
```

I want to implement *something* simple that will allow anonymous access to the `Register` method **only if** there is no user already registered.

Is it ok/good to extend `AllowAnonymous` filter so it does the check on Db before returning true/false or I should somehow implement a policy?

If extending the attribute nor using a custom policy are not a good solutions, what do you recommend?

Will be nice if someone could guide me with a sample on where/how to the custom logic.

The idea is for an admin section, so only registered users can't register new ones. But if there is no user registered (first deploying on empty database), I want the user to be able to register with a username/password.

Note from security standpoint: *Keep in mind that only domain specific emails can be registered, so even if a random user hits the public face registration page when no user is already registered it won't be able to register with his/her own personal email address*

If I should take any additional security consideration, I'm open to read about them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is just a one-off thing, I would just run the check directly in `Register`. Creating a custom attribute to decorate a single action method with is overkill.

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult Register()
{
    if (db.Users.Any())
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
    }

    return View();
}
```

Technically, since your post action is CSRF-protected, there's no way to successfully complete a post without hitting the get action first, but just to be thorough, you can add the code to both, if you like.

Comment: Interesting. To protect the post operation I should use a salt for that specific method so someone can't use a token from another part of the site. Right?